# Not able to call base class function

Tags: c++, inheritance

I don't understand why this code gives compilation error, it is not a case of overriding because the parameter list in the base and child class is different, so can anyone help me on this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base
{
    public:
    void func ( )
    { 
        cout<< a ;
    }

    protected:  
    int a;
};

class Drived : public Base
{
    public:
    void func ( int inVal) 
    { 
        cout<< b <<"-> "<<inVal;
    }

    protected:
    int b;
 };

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Drived d;
    d.func(); //->Compilation error why and how can we avoid it?
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When looking for a matching function, the compiler searches through successively larger scopes until it finds a scope that contains the correct name. Then (for a function call) it collects together everything in that scope with that name, and does overload resolution on them to find the right one to call. If none of them can be called, it stops, and it's an error. It does *not* continue to search through more scopes looking for another function to call.

To make things work, you can bring the name of the base class function into scope in the derived class:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
    using Base::func;   // <--- this is what we added
    void func ( int inVal) 
    { 
        cout<< b <<"-> "<<inVal;
    }

    protected:
    int b;
 };
```

With that in place, the compiler will treat `Derived::func` and `Base::func` as an overload set, and see that you haven't passed any parameters so `Base::func` is the only one you could be calling, so that's what it resolves to.

Comment: Will inheriting the base class not result in making the base class function available in same scope as the derived class function ?

Comment: @P3A: No. Each class defines a separate scope.

Answer (score 1):

The `func` in `Drived` hides the one in `Base`. The easiest way to call it is to specify the scope:

```
d.Base::func();
```

If `Base::func` was a virtual function however this would disable virtual dispatch. An alternative solution is to bring the `Base` declaration into the `Drived` class scope with a *using-declaration*:

```
class Drived : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::func;
    void func(int inVal)
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

paste this line and it will work

```
Drived d;
d.func(1); //whats changed?
return 0;
return 0;
```

I believe you should figure out the difference yourself. Its not that difficult. have a look